# strategy pattern with dictionary lookup

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, strategy-pattern

I'm writing a validation engine.

I'm given with an a object payload containing around list of ~40 different properties. Every property will undergo different validation.

The validations include checking if the field is a string and validating if the length exceeds permissible limit set by db and there are conditions to check null values and empty fields as well.

So, I thought of picking the strategy pattern.

Code:

```
 interface IValidationEngine
{
    Error Validate(string propName, dynamic propValue);
}

public class StringLengthValidator : IValidationEngine
{

    static Dictionary<string, int> sLengths = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public StringLengthValidator()
    {
        if (sLengths.Count == 0)
        {
            sLengths = new Dictionary<string, int>(){....};
        }
    }

    public Error Validate(string name, dynamic value)
    {

        var err = default(Error); 
        //logic here

        return err;
    }
}

public class MandatoryValidator : IValidationEngine
{

    public Error Validate(string name, dynamic value)
    {

        var err = default(Error); 
        //logic here

        return err;
    }
}

public class MandatoryStringLengthValidator : IValidationEngine
{

    public Error Validate(string name, dynamic value)
    {

        var e = default(Error);

        if (value == null || (value.GetType() == typeof(string) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)))
        {
            e = new Error()
            {
                //.. err info
            };
        }
        else
        {
            StringLengthValidator sl = new StringLengthValidator();
            e = sl.Validate(name, value);
        }

        return e;
    }
}
```

There is another class which I named it `ValidationRouter`. The job of this is to route to the specific validator (Think of this as a [Strategy as per pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern)).

I wrote the initial router to have a dictionary of keys and its respective objects map so that whatever comes in will match its key and calls its appropriate `validate()` method on the dictionary value. But as adding keys and values with new object creation. I think the class will take lot of memory as I've the object creation in the constructor.

So, I've added Lazy to the object creation and it ended up like this

Here is the code for router

```
public class ValidationRouter
{
    public Dictionary<string, Lazy<IValidationEngine>> strategies = new Dictionary<string, Lazy<IValidationEngine>>();

    public ValidationRouter()
    {
        var mandatoryStringLength = new Lazy<IValidationEngine>(() => new MandatoryStringLengthValidator());
        var mandatory = new Lazy<IValidationEngine>(() => new MandatoryValidator());
        var stringLength = new Lazy<IValidationEngine>(() => new StringLengthValidator());

        strategies.Add("position", mandatoryStringLength);
        strategies.Add("pcode", stringLength);
        strategies.Add("username", mandatoryStringLength);
        strategies.Add("description", stringLength);
        strategies.Add("sourcename", stringLength);

        //OMG: 35 more fields to be added to route to specific routers
    }

    public Error Execute(string name, dynamic value)
    {
        //Find appropriate field and route to its strategy
        var lowered = name.ToLower();
        if (!strategies.ContainsKey(lowered)) return default(Error);

        return strategies[lowered].Value.Validate(name, value);
    }
}
```

As you can see I need to add 35 more keys to dictionaries with appropriate strategies in the constructor.

Is the approach correct or is there any better way of routing to specific validator algorithms ?

I thought of object creation to be done by factory pattern with `Activator.CreateInstance` but not sure how to achieve as each of my properties will have different strategies.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen Fluent Validation ? https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

Comment: Why you do not use the built-in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` attributes?  Like `[MaxLengthAttribute]` to validate a string length. Seems to me like you are reinventing the wheel. See [Validation with the Data Annotation Validators (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs).

Comment: ~40 objects in a dictionary like this should not be heavy on memory.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider I thought of having those Data annotations but the model class is shared across different products. So, I'm advised not to modify it. The other option would be to map to different DTO to have annotations.

Comment: I would strongly prefer delegates. No need to start with a heavyweight design. Also... your concerns about performance are likely misplaced.

Comment: What happens with your validation if you have a `description` property in one class that requires a max length of 100chars and 50 chars in another class? How would you handle that?

Comment: Aluan : What makes you think delegates is more efficient than a Dictionary?

Comment: @DavidG the description field has max length of 500 chars. If it exceeds I'll add necessary error message to `Error` class and return that object.

Comment: You miss my point. Assuming the description property exists in two places with different lengths, your code can't handle that right?

Comment: @jdweng I wasn't assessing efficiency, I was assessing ease of composition and simplicity. Also, I didn't mean to suggest delegates as opposed to a dictionary, in fact a dictionary of delegates would be quite natural.

Comment: @DavidG Yes it cannot handle. But if you supply two different description properties, API won't receive in the first place to go a head for validation.